# How to set max results for Pagination in TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I want to use pagination on a large dataset.
Until now, the following has been working well.

```
await myRepository.findAndCount({
      where: whereClauses,
      skip: currentPage * pageSize,
      take: pageSize
)};
```

My problem is in the following situation:
Say I have `pageSize=1000` and the result set is 300,000 results. The `findAndCount` method is still taking a long time to complete. I would like to set something like a `maxResults` where the highest possible number of pages would be `maxResults/pageSize` in order to reduce the processing time.

In the case above, with a `pageSize` of 1,000 and total results of 300k, the max results would prevent me from ever counting the full 300k dataset, instead cutting it off at 100k.

I would still like to use the `findAndCount` functionality so that on my UI, I can keep showing users how many pages of data exist (i.e. "You are on Page 3 of 100") but throw up a warning if they hit the max number of results.

Is this possible in typeORM?

Comment: I didnt deeply tested, but I found that executing 2 queries is more efficient than using `findAndCount`.  so I'm running a `count` query first to get the total expected records, then the `find` query with pagination boundaries. Not the most beautiful way, but the most efficient for tables with millions of lines

Comment: Just had a talk with the rest of the team and this is the solution we are going to take for now. Thanks!